# React, Redux, and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm getting started with react (have been working with it for a couple weeks now) and I'm now stumbling across using firebase with redux and react. I have tried researching countless times what the point is of using both, because I have come across infinite projects on youtube or google where developers will use both of them. They use firebase (or the firestore) to store data, and then use Redux in React to communicate with the client. This doesn't make sense to me though, because wouldn't it be much easier to simply use firebase and just use the get and set methods it provides to update data directly in firebase? What is the point of using Redux as a middleground?

For example, if I was to make a web application such that:
You could log in, and then have a dashboard with lots of different tasks that all the users who have logged in have submitted over time. So multiple people could submit tasks and it would just display them on the dashboard.

I have seen this project on youtube and the creator used firebase to store the users and the posts, and used redux as well. But wouldn't it be much more efficient to use firebase and update the tasks/users directly from there, with no redux involved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very good reason to use all 3.

React is there as the UI layer that the user interacts with to make calls. You can of course store state locally with React in components and sometimes there is no need for Redux.

Redux comes in when your apps state gets complicated (hence, it's a state management framework). instead of passing down potentially loads of props from parent to child and then even needing these props in completely different areas of the codebase and having to reshuffle your app to suit this accordingly, Redux allows you to put all the state in a central store so that any component can `connect` to the store and request the `state` it requires. It's not always necessary and should only be used when your state becomes unmanageable purely with React

Firebase is obviously a database and is completely different to the two of them. the main difference being that state is `ephemeral` in React and Redux, meaning that it's short lived. on a page refresh you will lose all component state with React and Redux and it'll be "reset" to the initial state. You use firebase when you want to persist data and store it for users who are going to keep coming back to your app and need to see their previous data. e.g. Facebook. They don't use Firebase but when you return to the app again, you need to know all your data, the things you've liked, the friends you've connected with e.g. This is all stored in the database.

In terms of the example you gave. It makes sense to store the users in firebase (because that'll be needed when the user returns next time to the app) but it also makes sense in Redux. Let's say you have a component that needs to show the users profile. Well React can connect to the Redux store and get that user info. But if you're app is super huge and say a completely different component needs to know the users hobbies for example. Well that component can also request from Redux. You could obviously not use Redux but it would mean React would have to control the WHOLE apps component state and once you have a big app, it becomes very hard to maintain

Let me know if that helps or if you have further questions!

Comment: Ahhh I see, so it's mostly just to not have your React handle an entire database at once, and instead allow Redux to do the searching. So basically, the Redux would get things and set things in firebase, and store it in a state, and your React would just interact with Redux? Thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: @tsnakejake yeh pretty much. in Redux we dispatch "actions" and they update the store. I would still have React update firebase (I do that in my project anyway). Once the firebase database is updated, you can update the Redux store to reflect the changes locally so that they aren't out of sync. up vote the answer if you think it was useful and happy to help you again if you have any more questions!

Comment: Last question, sorry mate! If we end up updating both Redux store and Firebase, then what's the main point? Is it so that next time, we can just go directly to the Redux store and not all the way to the API? Also, I tried upvoting your answer but it says i'm too much of a beginner to give feedback D:

Comment: no problem! the reason why you need to update both is if you only update Redux and then your user leaves the app they will come back and not see the new data (as it hasn't been stored in the database). imagine if your app lets you upload photos. your user uploads a photo and can see it as their new profile photo as that is how your react/redux state is rendering it. they leave the app, come back in a few days. the photo is now know longer there. why? because it wasn't persisted in a database. think database === persistence. redux === makes local state more easily manageable

Comment: Got it. You're the best! Wish I could upvote. Have a good one, cheers!

Comment: if you want to accept the answer, that will also help! :D have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

In short:
Redux has been used to manage state for a long time.
It is why there are so many examples online.

A bit longer:
Here are some examples of why to use Redux, or any state container/management.

---

Imagine an application where we get user profile data...

***Without Redux***:
*1st time*
User clicks on profile -> User sees a spinner -> Data from user profile is fetched -> Data from user profile is returned -> Spinner removed -> Profile data is on page

*2nd time*
User clicks on profile -> User sees a spinner -> Data from user profile is fetched -> Data from user profile is returned -> Spinner removed -> Profile data is on page

As you can see, each time the profile page is clicked, the user profile is fetched. So we have 2 calls to an API to retrieve profile data (profile data that probably hasn't changed).

-

***With Redux:***
*1st time*
User clicks on profile -> No data found in Redux state -> User sees a spinner -> Data from user profile is fetched -> Data from user profile is returned  -> Data is stored in Redux state -> Spinner removed -> Profile data is on page

*2nd time*
User clicks on profile -> Profile data found in Redux state -> Profile data is on page

In this case, the user profile is only loaded once. (Reloading of data in the background is also a possibility)

---

But now imagine another component using profile data...
Example: Next to the logout button, there is a profile image or "Hello username".

So there are 2 components using profile data. Without using a state container such as Redux, Context or whatever you like to use, you'd have to fetch profile data for each component each time the component is shown.

The data has already been loaded, so there's no reason to fetch the data again and leave the end-user waiting. Again, we can fetch data in the background and refresh it when the data is returned. If we are sure the data hasn't changed, we don't even have to put stress on the API.

The same applies to tasks or other data. A user doesn't want to wait. As a developer, you want to render the application as soon as possible. You can use data that is already available or get data from a cache and show it on screen. The redux-persist package helps to retain data over browser sessions.

---

There are a bunch of other reasons why anyone would use Redux:
 - Maintainability
 - Debugging / Testing
 - Predictability
 - ...

Comment: Thank you so much! Your example helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

`Redux` and `Firebase Store` are two completely different things that designed for different purposes. Whether to use any of them in the app is your decision. I think you have a really good question as many developers just use whatever they see in the tutorial or other developers using without really question the purposes.

`Firebase Store` is the service designed for use to store the application data persistently. It can be seen as part of the serverless or backend-as-a-service (BAAS) that Google offers. It's popular because it saves developer time of setting up and running your own persistent storage service. Alternatives for `Firebase store` can be AWS Dynamo DB or any kind of database server you can come up with. Usually, for a web application, you only store the most business critical data to a persistent storage. These data can be user or product information and transaction details.

`Redux` is a state management library or framework. Its purpose is to allow you manage the data that describe the state of your application at any given time. Usually, a real-life web application has several different interactive, moving components that their states change continuously. For example, things such as buttons, lists of data, inputs and forms can have multiple different states such as pending, ready. The states of these elements can be changed by user interactions or the availability of external data. `Redux` is designed to have with storing, keeping track and managing these states. It works really well with React by allowing the UI component to response to these state changes in a declarative way. A popular alternative for Redux is `mobx`.

Usually, if your web application is simple and doesn't have many interactive components, (for example, a blog website), then you can ignore Redux, you can simply query and persist the data directly from Firebase, it's a completely fine approach that actually I have seen in several startups' MVPs. However, if you are dealing with a complex application that have multiple different components interact with each other (for example), then using a state management library will be beneficial and recommended. It will keep you and the people you are working with sane.